# Adding a Google Re-CAPTCHA form to PHP "Contact us form"

Tags: javascript, php, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a newbie in terms of web develpoment and I'm stuck with an issue with a contact form on which I'm trying to attach a captcha field to prevent spamming.

Before adding the captcha form, the code worked and the e-mails were sent.After adding the captcha validation , the JS file shows a success confirmation message but the e-mails were not sent.

Code us detailed below :

**HTML:**

```
 <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                    //rest of the inputs 
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site_key_here"></div>
                            <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please check that you are not a robot.</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="submit">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

function errorResponse ($messsage) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
  return false;
}

// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name']) ||  empty($_POST['email']) ||     empty($_POST['phone'])   || empty($_POST['message']) ||     !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
  echo "No arguments Provided!";
  return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = '_email_here_';
$email_subject = "Contact Form from website:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact   form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail:   $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 

//MY CODE STARTS HERE
// getting the captcha
$captcha = "";
if (isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])) {
      $captcha = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
}
else {
    return false;
}

// handling the captcha and checking if it's ok
$secret = "_secret_key_here_";
$google_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$google_response = file_get_contents($google_url);

$response = json_decode($google_response, true);
// if the captcha is cleared with google, send the mail and return.
if ($response["success"] != false) {
    // send the actual mail
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    // return goes back to the ajax, so the user can know if everything is ok
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
//AND ENDS HERE
?>
```

Before the captcha validation the code was:

```
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: The e-mails are not sending . I may have missed that , sorry

Comment: Try with `@mail()`

Comment: With `@mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);` does not work :(

Comment: Using '@' is not actually a good practice. But it's usefull for some nu-necessary error handling.

Comment: Not only is bad practice, there is practically no way it could solve the problem...

Comment: @BMU what happened, if you not using CAPTCHA means ? 
Is mail sent successfully ??

Comment: Problem is very probably related to your checking of re-captcha response. Use something like this (https://github.com/google/recaptcha) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan if i replace the PHP code from `//MY CODE STARTS HERE` with `mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true; ` it works, and I receive the email

Comment: @BMU Reason is that, Some time these reCAPTCHA's are having issue on quick response due to network traffic. Here, you only focused on "Success" state. So You couldn't recognize the actual issue around that. So make log of reCAPTCHA response .You may get an Idea....

Comment: Try using something like PEAR, it has great PHP packages to mail users. https://pear.php.net/package/Mail

Comment: How are you confirming that your PHP code is returning `true`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found here : https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-recaptcha
Topic closed.